# How to hide link in navbar if user is not admin MERN app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jwt, admin, mern

I want to hide some link addnew link is user is not admin. I am using MERN stack to create app and i have access token in cookies now i don't know how to hide this link

Nav bar

```js
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { FaBars, FaTimes } from "react-icons/fa";
import "./Navbar.css";
import {
  NavBar,
  Nav_Logo,
  Nav_Links,
  Nav_Item,
  NavBar_Container,
} from "../../../Styled-Components/Navbar";
import { IconContext } from "react-icons/lib";
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";
import Modal from "../Contact Form/Modal";
import ContactForm from "../Contact Form/ContactForm";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import ToggleSwitch from "../ToggleSwitch/ToggleSwitch";
import { logout } from "../../../Redux/authRedux";
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'

export default function Navbar() {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
  const [button, setButton] = useState(true);
  const [overflow, setOverFlow] = useState(true);
  const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);

  const currentUser = useSelector((state) => state.auth.currentUser);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  function closeModal() {
    setModalOpen(false);
  }

  function openModal() {
    setModalOpen(true);
  }

  function handleClick() {
    setClick(!click);
  }

  function closeMobileMenu() {
    setClick(false);
  }

  function showButton() {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 960) {
      setButton(false);
    } else {
      setButton(true);
    }
  }

  function closeMobileMenu() {
    setClick(false);
  }

  function handleLogout() {
    Cookies.remove('accessToken');
    dispatch(logout());
    closeMobileMenu();
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    showButton();
  }, []);

  window.addEventListener("resize", showButton);

  return (
    <>
      <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: "#fff" }}>
        <NavBar>
          <NavBar_Container>
            <Nav_Logo to="/" onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
              AmProMotors
            </Nav_Logo>
            <div className="menu-icon" onClick={handleClick}>
              {click ? (
                <FaTimes style={{ color: "black" }} />
              ) : (
                <FaBars style={{ color: "black" }} />
              )}
            </div>

            {/* Navbar Items  */}

            <ul className={click ? "nav-menu active" : "nav-menu"}>
              <Nav_Item>
                <Nav_Links to="/" onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                  Home
                </Nav_Links>
              </Nav_Item>

              <Nav_Item>
                <Nav_Links to="/about-us" onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                  About Us
                </Nav_Links>
              </Nav_Item>

              <Nav_Item>
                <Nav_Links to="/gallary" onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                  Gallary
                </Nav_Links>
              </Nav_Item>
              <Nav_Item>
                {currentUser ? (
                  <Nav_Links to={"/"} onClick={handleLogout}>
                    Logout
                  </Nav_Links>
                ) : (
                  <Nav_Links to="/login" onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                    Login
                  </Nav_Links>
                )}
              </Nav_Item>
              <Nav_Item>
                <Nav_Links to="/add-new" onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                  Add New
                </Nav_Links>
              </Nav_Item>
              <ToggleSwitch />

              {/* Main button */}

              <li className="nav-btn">
                {button ? (
                  <Link to="" className="btn-link">
                    <motion.button
                      whileHover={{ scale: 1.1 }}
                      whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
                      className="btn--outline"
                      onClick={() => (modalOpen ? closeModal() : openModal())}
                    >
                      CONTACT US
                    </motion.button>
                  </Link>
                ) : (
                  <Link to="" className="btn-link" onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                    <motion.button
                      whileHover={{ scale: 1.1 }}
                      whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
                      className="btn--mobile"
                      style={{ overflow: overflow ? "hidden" : "visible" }}
                      buttonSize="btn--mobile"
                      buttonStyle="btn--outline"
                      onClick={() => {
                        modalOpen ? closeModal() : openModal(),
                          setOverFlow(!overflow);
                      }}
                    >
                      Contact US
                    </motion.button>
                  </Link>
                )}
              </li>
            </ul>
          </NavBar_Container>
        </NavBar>
        <AnimatePresence
          // Disable any initial animations on children that
          // are present when the component is first rendered
          initial={false}
          // Only render one component at a time.
          // The exiting component will finish its exit
          // animation before entering component is rendered
          exitBeforeEnter={true}
          // Fires when all exiting nodes have completed animating out
          onExitComplete={() => null}
        >
          {modalOpen && (
            <ContactForm modalOpen={modalOpen} handleClose={closeModal} />
          )}
        </AnimatePresence>
      </IconContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}
```

I am using redux toolkit and i have current user with is admin set to true can i use that or i have to use access token to check if user is admin or not and how to do it...?

Answer (score 3):

If you have isAdmin property in currentUser you cand do something like :

```
 {currentUser?.isAdmin && ( 
     <Nav_Item>
        <Nav_Links to="/add-new" onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
              Add New
        </Nav_Links>
     </Nav_Item>
)}
```